# jQuery ajax call "Not Found" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I have been trying to make a ajax call to a JSP page. Here's the piece of JS function.

```
<script>
$(function(){

  function myAjaxCall() {
     $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "jsp/common/myJavascriptPage.jsp",
        dataType: "text",
        success: 
            function (result) {
               alert("Got the result: " + result);
            },
            error: function (xhr,status,error) {
               alert("Status: " + status);
               alert("Error: " + error);
               alert("xhr: " + xhr.readyState);
            },
            statusCode: {
               404: function() {
                   alert("page not found");
               }
            }
        });
   }
 });
 </script>
```

I am constantly getting file not found, even though JSP exists in the URL mentioned. Please note that I am calculating the JSP file location relative to that of webapp directory.

I tried using the normal AJAX calls (without jQuery), but ended up with same error.

Could you please help me understand why is it not able to locate the jsp?

Comment: First and foremost, what does jsp/common/myJavascriptPage.jsp return?

Comment: could you try changing the `url` to `"/jsp/common/myJavascriptPage.jsp"` in your call?

Comment: I am just returning a piece of text. It has a java code embedded to it. I am using `response.getWriter().println(myResponse);`

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Just tried it. Didn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Please note that I am calculating the JSP file location relative to that of webapp directory.

This is where you're going wrong.

AJAX is being executed from the client's web browser, meaning that it's not relative to anything on the server.

If you were to hit that page in a web browser, where you would go?

That's where you want your request URL to be.

**Edit: I clearly didn't explain this well  enough, so that's have another go!**

Let's say I have a file on my server that's stored like so:

`my_website/src/webapp/jsp/common/myFile.jsp`

If I wanted to access this resource through a *publicly accessible URL*, it would not be the same as the file path above. It might be something like `common/myFile.jsp` or maybe even `common/myFile`.

If this were the case, then I must use the *publicly accessible URL* for an AJAX request to be able to sent to that URL.

Comment: I will needs to stay on the same page. The JSP just has a Java code embedded in this which returns with a text, which needs to be updated in the index.jsp file.

Comment: That's fine! AJAX, in simplest terms, just means that you're making an HTTP request and aren't worried about when it comes back. It's no different than visiting a page in your browser. When the request is sent, you will not be redirected to that page or otherwise.

Comment: Okay. So the URL must stay to "index.jsp". If yes, then how do I call the JSP page to retrieve the response from it?

Comment: All you do is replace the current URL that you have (`jsp/common/myJavascriptPage.jsp`) to be the URL you would visit if you were trying to access it from a web browser. ie something like `http://mydomain.com/myJavascriptPage.jsp`.

Comment: Still not very clear on this. Why would I need to use Ajax if I want to load some other page? Plus, even examples on jQuery ajax API website doesn't seem to include domain in the url. [Check](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not trying to say you have to include domain. Check my edit, maybe this explanation will make more sense to you.

Comment: Appreciate the help Ian. It does make sense now. :) Though doesn't solve my problem. I will move the embedded java code to a servlet (I guess that would be a cleaner way). Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your URL is incomplete. The most likely cause for the error is that you dont have a fully qualified URL.

Try specifying the full path and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following two points on the Page Not found error. I also faced the same problem. My case I was calling a json file to load the data. After correcting the below corrections, it started working fine.

**(1) The File path (URL) should be relative to the current page where the script exeutes**

**(2) Add the .json (text/plain) MIME extension in the IIS Server.**